XCode upgrade to v16 to support iOS 18 results in failure
My project of a year has been working fine.  On Sept 16, i was forced to update XCode to support iOS 18.  Since then, I am completely blocked.  The error is vague:

unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Build again to continue.

-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               XCBBuildService [91814]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/XCBuild.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/XCBBuildService.bundle/Contents/MacOS/XCBBuildService
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.XCBBuildService
Version:               1.0 (23000.1.226)
Build Info:            XCBuild-23000001226000000~21 (16A242d)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Xcode [76424]
Responsible:           Xcode [76424]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-09-20 18:30:19.1728 -0600
OS Version:            macOS 15.0 (24A335)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        6FC4E806-2F4A-575D-F3A9-1370AF3AB4EA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       94E36EBE-9802-4D50-89E2-B0A02EE6A676

Time Awake Since Boot: 88000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5823 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        14

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   XCBBuildService [91814]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x3) mach_vm_allocate_kernel failed within call to vm_map_enter


Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x183671e34 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1836845d0 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18367a9d8 mach_msg_overwrite + 480
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18367217c mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18379a5bc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x183798e6c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
6   CoreFoundation                         0x183798334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
7   CoreFoundation                         0x183813a10 CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x25ce54554 swift_task_asyncMainDrainQueueImpl() + 40
9   libswift_Concurrency.dylib             0x25ce54514 swift_task_asyncMainDrainQueue + 92
10  XCBBuildService                        0x1047ef92c main + 84
11  dyld                                   0x183330274 start + 2840

I have tried:

uninstalling & reinstalling XCode
Updated my MacOS to Sequoia 15.0 (24A335)

In My Expo project, I have removed ios folder.  I have deleted yarn.lock and reinstalled all packages from scratch.
What is it about the Apple XCode update that is causing this crash?  What else can I try?
